# Uploading .pom file via node-bintray

Tags: android, node.js, maven, pom.xml, bintray

I am having a strange issue where uplading a `.pom` file via the [node-bintray](https://github.com/h2non/node-bintray) package results in a 400.

All other file uploads are functioning correctly, and I can't find any documentation that might explain why a `.pom` file should be different.

The pom file being uploaded is that which is generated by the `com.github.dcendents.android-maven` gradle plugin.

Below is a code sample that reproduces the issue:

```
const repository = new Bintray({
    username: bintrayProps.BINTRAY_USER,
    apikey: bintrayProps.BINTRAY_API_KEY,
    organization: bintrayProps.BINTRAY_ORG,
    repository: bintrayProps.BINTRAY_MAVEN_REPO
});

repository.uploadPackage('packageName', '1.0.0', './myPomFile.xml', 'my/group/artifactId/1.0.0/artifactId-1.0.0-myPomFile.pom', false);
```

The error message is as follows:

> Unable to upload files: Could not extract metadata for artifact \'my/group/artifactId/1.0.0/artifactId-1.0.0-myPomFile.pom\', content might be malformed.

Example pom file::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>aar</packaging>
    <name>MyPackage</name>
    <url>http://my-site.io</url>
</project>
```

Changing the remote path to have any other extension results in a successful upload.

**EDIT**

Changed the remote path to match the pom file to rule out that issue.

**EDIT 2**

I've narrowed down the issue to a specific file path... It seems to only reproduce when the remote path follows the structure seen above `my/group/artifactId/version/artifactId-version-myPomFile.pom`

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the issue to be in the `node-bintray` package. The package was uploading to bintray using multipart, but that is not accepted by Bintray and the files all end up corrupted.

Uploading via `inputStream` using the `request` package functions correctly.

```js
readStream = fs.createReadStream filePath
return request.put {
    url: Bintray.apiBaseUrl + endpoint,
    body: readStream,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": mimeType
    }
    auth: {
        user: @rest.options.username
        pass: @rest.options.password
    }
}
```